# Active verbs with passive meaning when followed by 'gerund' or 'to-infinitive'

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, gerunds, active-voice, infinitive-vs-gerund

One of my friends told me that some verbs have passive meanings when they are followed by a gerund, and they have both active and passive meanings when they are followed by **to-infinitive**. I asked him about the name of those verbs, and requested him to give some examples. He told me that '**need, require and want**' are such kind of verbs, but he couldn't give any examples.

Would anybody give some examples to make this topic clear? Are there other verbs except '**want, need and require**', which follow the rules stated above?

Comment: Nice question. Here are some examples, but I don't have time to do a good answer: *The care needs washing*, *Your hair wants cutting*, *Do the carpets require cleaning?*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Araucaria exposed, after the verbs *deserve, need, want* and *require*, the —*ing* form has a passive sense.
Michael Swan's — *Practical English Usage* states that this is more common in BrE than AmE. The following examples are taken from his book:

> ## —ing forms (4): after verbs
>
> #### 3   —*ing* form with passive meaning.
>
> » *I don't think his article **deserves reading*** = (...) deserves **to be read**.
>          » *Your hair **needs cutting*** = (...) needs **to be cut**.
>   In informal British English, *want* can also be used like this.
>          » *The car **wants servicing*** = (...) needs **to be serviced**.

Answer (score 0):

The gerund used after these verbs indicates that the subject needs or requires or wants (in a somewhat idiomatic, metaphoric, passive way, since inanimate objects can't rightfully *need* or *require*, much less *want*, anything, as such) some sort of action performed on it.

> This type of carpet requires frequent shampooing.
>
> The car needs washing.
>
> The lawn wants mowing.

Conversely, the to-infinitive indicates that someone is requesting or demanding that these actions be performed:

> The landlord requires tentants to shampoo the carpet every month.
>
> Your father needs you to wash the car.
>
> I want you to mow the lawn this Saturday.